# Prevent Toggle Navbar Icon Stacking on Top of Brand Logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using an image with img-responsive class on brand logo, how do you prevent the toggle icon that shows when the navbar collapses from stacking on top of the logo image? What I want is for the logo to scale down as browser window scales down.

See a quick example of my problem here:
http://www.bootply.com/UP2MFV011K#

My  logo is 398x120 px and it needs to have the navheader's height to allow for its size. Then when the browser window scales down, to scale down the logo image, but to not allow toggle nav icon to stack on top. At present the toggle icon will eventually stack on top before the logo starts to scale down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in bootstrap images have a min-width of 100% which means it will move the navigaiton once the browser window is small enough to make room for it's 100% width.  Probably the easiest solution would be to change the .navbar-brand width down to 80% on mobile size screens.  And adding `height:auto;` will give you your desired responsive height.

```
.navbar-brand{
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}
```

See my solution.

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/OMdWGy

Comment: Yea, that works fairly well, except once you reach 311 px width, then the image jumps down. Of course, at that small a window it may be of no worry, but it would still be nice to see the image continue to scale on down and not jump below toggle nav. Also, how to get height of navbar-header to match its height to the image, so the image doesn't overlap it, and then both to scale down responsively.

Comment: if you add a container around the button you can add some styling to force it to be in the remaining 20% of the width.  Also, adding `.navbar-brand{height:auto;}` will get you the height you are looking for.  See my codepen link above to see it in action.  You'll have to do some additional css if you need the nav links bottom aligned but this at least answers your question.